# How to save Custom Order attribute when inputting via cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, cart, custom-field

I have created a custom order field using the below code:

```
<?php require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')- 
>load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
'type'          => 'varchar',
'backend_type'  => 'varchar',
'frontend_input' => 'varchar',
'is_user_defined' => true,
'label'         => 'PO Number',
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'user_defined'  => false,
'searchable'    => false,
'filterable'    => false,
'comparable'    => false,
'default'       => ''
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'customer_po_number', $attribute);
$installer->addAttribute('quote', 'customer_po_number', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();

echo "success";
```

There is no payment section on the website, only billing/shipping details so I was going to add the field just before the final submit button. What process would I need to go through to get it to populate the order field via the cart?

Is it as simple as an input field with the correct name? I am assuming not.

Any help much appreciated!!

Many Thanks
Iskander